# Put one signal into phase with another

Tags: complex-numbers

I am given two signals:

```
Signal 1 = 2cos(1500t + 2pi/3)

Signal 2 = Bcos(1500t + 5pi/5)
```

The question asks what value of B creates a 0 degrees difference in phase.

My initial approach would be to put both of these into a complex form, and solve for B somehow. But I am not sure the correct way to go about this...

Comment: Isn't $B$ amplitude? Why would $B$ affect the phase?

Comment: I don't think so? Thats what i was confused about